# Syncing Folders in Skydrive pro over RDS

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to understand the technology a little bit better before I proceed with the setup. Using office 365, I am wondering if I have a folder and I want 40 users accessing from skydrive pro, do each of them on their individual accounts sync that folder to their machines? Or can it be set up where the updated synced folder is hosted on its own server, and the 40 users sync to that one. That way preventing 40 downloads of the same thing.

I hope this makes sense, and if it doesn't I am hoping someone can fill me in a little bit better.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find an answer in the meantime?